# spring cloud - bootstrap.properties outside my jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to put `bootstrap.properties` from outside my jar, so it won't get overridden by other developers by mistake. Could you please advice here?

This is its' content - directing to the spring server config

```
# application name
spring.application.name=elixium
# The server entry point
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? What have you tried? If you've tried something, and failed, what was the error?

Comment: I have tried using @PropertyResource and he ignored the external location and started on tomcat default port

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Cloud uses the the same [locations as spring boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) to find `bootstrap.properties` (or `.yml`). So `classpath:,classpath:/config,file:,file:config/` is the default search path, `./config/` is the highest precedence. If your file is in `./config` or `./` it should just work. The property (`spring.cloud.bootstrap.location`) to [change the location](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-commons.adoc#changing-the-location-of-bootstrap-properties) is slightly different than boot.

Comment: Thanks Spencer , yes I would like to change it's location . So should I use spring.cloud.bootstrap.location inside bootstrap.properties ?

Comment: No, it needs to be a env var, cmd line arg or java system property, otherwise you get a chicken and egg problem. How can you read the location of `bootstrap.properties` if you don't know the location ahead of time.

Comment: Well It can reach bootstrap.properties but I want to direct it outside my jar

Comment: I have tried to use as enviorment parameters spring.cloud.bootstrap.location=C:\test\test.. This did not work  and i have tried to do the same as cmd line param. Maybe can you link me to an example for this 2 approaches? I have tried to change location but it is not clear how. Tnx

Comment: Thank you Spencer - I have solved it with environment variable :   spring.cloud.bootstrap.location    C:\tradair\config\tang\bootstrap.properties

Comment: AND also updated to 1.04 version  :                                        <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I solved it by adding --spring.cloud.bootstrap.location={{app_dir}}/bootstrap.properties in service file while starting application

Answer (score 2):

`spring.cloud.bootstrap.location` behaves like `spring.config.location` (in Spring Boot 2), it replaces the location of these configuration files.

To make it working, it has to defined as a system property.
For example :

With Jar :

```
java -jar
     -Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.location=anyLocation/bootstrap.yml 
      ...
```

With Spring Boot maven plugin :

```
mvn spring-boot:run 
   -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.location=anyLocation/bootstrap.yml"
```